# Find a function $f(x)$ whose derivative in the sense of distributions is the distribution $x^2+4x+\delta_2$

Tags: solution-verification, distribution-theory

For my PDE class, I need to solve the following problem:

> Find a function $f(x)$ whose derivative in the sense of distributions is the distribution $x^2+4x+\delta_2$

**MY PROOF**

$$\langle(F_f)',\phi(x)\rangle=\langle x^2+4x+\delta_2,\phi(x)\rangle \\[3ex]
\begin{align*}-\langle F_f,\phi(x)'\rangle&=\left\langle \left(\frac{x^3}{3}+2x^2+H(x-2)\right)',\phi(x)\right\rangle \\[1ex] &=-\left\langle \frac{x^3}{3}+2x^2+H(x-2),\phi'(x)\right\rangle\end{align*} \\[10ex]
\Rightarrow \, f(x)=\frac{x^3}{3}+2x^2+H(x-2)$$

I know my final result is correct but I was wondering if my proof was also correct. I feel like I need to detail more how I got from the first line to the second line but I'm not sure how to do it and still be correct. Otherwise, I can always say that $f(x)$ is equal to that and then take the derivative and conclude that $f'(x)$ is indeed equal to $x^2+4x+\delta_2$ in the sense of distributions that but that's much longer to write.

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: I don't see the point of writing those steps when you really are just using the fact that you know an antiderivative of each term. Differentiation is linear, so your answer is correct.

Comment: Can you also give *all* "primitive distributions" to $x^2+4x+\delta_2$?

Comment: @md2perpe I forgot the +C thanks